# Deserializing struct from file yields wrong result

Tags: rust

I have a problem reading serialized data from a file. I first serialize a struct called `Foo` with a u64 field called `bar`. Then I write it to a file. I will do this in a loop four times. Afterwards I want to read the entries from the file and deserialize them, again with a loop. However this gives me wrong results. Only the first and the last entries are correct. Those between have the same `bar` value like the first struct (bar value 0).

result I get:

```
foo: Foo { bar: 0 }
foo: Foo { bar: 0 }
foo: Foo { bar: 0 }
foo: Foo { bar: 3 }
```

expected result:

```
foo: Foo { bar: 0 }
foo: Foo { bar: 1 }
foo: Foo { bar: 2 }
foo: Foo { bar: 3 }
```

Here my cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bincode = "1.3.3"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

And here main.rs:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::SeekFrom;

const PAGE_SIZE: usize = 8;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: u64,
}

fn serialize_to_file(id: u64, file_name: &str) -> usize {
    let mut file = File::create(file_name).unwrap();
    let foo = Foo { bar: id };
    let encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&foo).unwrap();
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(id * PAGE_SIZE as u64)).unwrap();
    file.write(&encoded).unwrap()
}

fn deserialize_page_from_file(id: u64, file_name: &str) -> Foo {
    let mut file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
    let mut vec = vec![0u8; PAGE_SIZE];
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(id * PAGE_SIZE as u64)).unwrap();
    file.read(vec.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
    bincode::deserialize(&vec[..]).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let test_file = "foo.txt";
    for j in 0..4 {
        let bytes_writen = serialize_to_file(j, test_file);
        println!("bytes written: {:?}", bytes_writen);
    }

    for k in 0..4 {
        let foo: Foo = deserialize_page_from_file(k, test_file);
        println!("foo: {:?}", foo);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create

Comment: *"This function will create a file if it does not exist, **and will truncate it if it does**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Herohtar mentioned, you are truncating the file with `fn serialize_to_file`,
you are creating the file 5 times,this would be a simple solution.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::SeekFrom;

const PAGE_SIZE: usize = 8;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: u64,
}

fn serialize_to_file(id: u64, file_name: &mut File) -> usize {
    let foo = Foo { bar: id };
    let encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&foo).unwrap();
    file_name.seek(SeekFrom::Start(id * PAGE_SIZE as u64)).unwrap();
    file_name.write(&encoded).unwrap()
}

fn deserialize_page_from_file(id: u64, file_name: &str) -> Foo {
    let mut file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
    let mut vec = vec![0u8; PAGE_SIZE];
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(id * PAGE_SIZE as u64)).unwrap();
    file.read(vec.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
    bincode::deserialize(&vec[..]).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let test_file = "foo.txt";
    let mut file = File::create(test_file).unwrap();
    for j in 0..4 {
        let bytes_writen = serialize_to_file(j, &mut file);
        println!("bytes written: {:?}", bytes_writen);
    }

    for k in 0..4 {
        let foo: Foo = deserialize_page_from_file(k, test_file);
        println!("foo: {:?}", foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. though I decided to use the OpenOptions struct for my use case. I somehow misunderstood "truncate"